# System menu of Win32 dialog uses classic (unthemed) style and acts weird

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, uxtheme

I'm opening a dialog with `DialogBoxW` and for whatever reason, its system menu (the titlebar menu) uses the classic theme (unthemed) style and acts weird. The menu items in it only actually perform the actions half the time, and the rest of the time, it just reopens the menu again. Here's my DlgProc.

```c
void DlgProc(
    HWND   hWnd,
    UINT   uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND hFileLabel = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDD_OPENWITH_FILE);
            SetWindowTextW(hFileLabel, szFileName);
            break;
        }
        default:
            DefWindowProcW(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }
}
```

I've added the Common Controls 6.0 dependency and the dialog itself is themed so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: A dialog box procedure returns a BOOL. And returns TRUE if the message is processed otherwise FALSE and does not call DefWindowProc.

Comment: @CGi03 Thanks! That fixed the odd menu behavior. However, the menu's still rendering with classic theme...

Comment: It seems to me that the system menu is identical with or without a theme. It uses the Windows theme.

Comment: @CGi03 I have the default Windows 10 theme applied, and everything else is themed, but the title bar menu of that particular dialog is just classic theme for some reason.

Comment: Have you added an application manifest or compiler directive to specify that version 6 should be used. For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Yes, I have.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid dialog procedure. A dialog procedure **must** have [this signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc):

> ```c
> INT_PTR Dlgproc(
>   HWND unnamedParam1,
>   UINT unnamedParam2,
>   WPARAM unnamedParam3,
>   LPARAM unnamedParam4
> )
> ```

The dialog manager uses the return value for various things. Since your "dialog procedure" doesn't return a value, the dialog manager is operating on indeterminate values. The behavior is thus undefined.

Comment: While the page you linked does have `INT_PTR` in the signature, it says "None" under the Return value section, so I have no idea what I'm supposed to return...

Comment: The documentation, unfortunately, got butchered during the most recent update and shows *"None"* in the return value section for things where this obviously isn't true. Here, however, all the information just moved up to the parameters section named *"Additional message-specific information."* With the exception of a handful of messages, you'll want to return `TRUE` if you don't want the system to handle the message, and `FALSE` otherwise.